# gnuplot replot: "Scan size of matrix is zero"

Tags: python, gnuplot

I am trying to (frequently, e.g. every 0.01s) replot a 2D dataset in gnuplot, by generating a small (e.g. 10x10) 2D numpy array in python and saving it to a file.

Running the following works for a couple of seconds and then gnuplot stops with the error, "Scan size of matrix is zero".

```
gnuplot > plot 'testfile.out' matrix w image
gnuplot > while(1) {replot; pause 0.01;}
```

How can I get gnuplot to ignore this and continue replotting the data file?

---

**Edit:**
The method below works fine for the random number generator, but when I apply it to my actual file the same thing happens with "scan size of matrix is zero". Possibly it's an issue with Python rather than gnuplot? To be precise, I am running `setup-and-plot.gp` from the answer below:

```
    set term wxt noraise
    plot '<flock testfile.out cat testfile.out' matrix w image
    while(1) { pause 0.01; replot; }
```

and then the following Python code:

```
    import time
    import numpy as np

    while True:
        # in actual code array is not random, this is just to debug.
        arr = np.random.rand(10,10)
        np.savetxt('testfile.out', arr)
        time.sleep(.01)
```

After a few seconds (depending on how long I set the sleep time) it stops again, with the "scan size of matrix is zero" error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can.

A workaround is to use file-locking, e.g. below is an example using a Gnuplot script and a random number generator using flock from the `util-linux` package:

*setup-and-plot.gp*

```gnuplot
set term wxt noraise
plot '<flock testfile.out cat testfile.out' matrix w image
while(1) { pause 0.01; replot; }
```

The generator (tested with bash):

```bash
while sleep .01; do 
  flock testfile.out \
    sh -c "shuf -i 0-100 -n100 | xargs -n10 > testfile.out"
done
```

Run the generator in one terminal and `gnuplot setup-and-plot.gp` in another.  Make sure you are in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks, this works for your example, but strangely doesn't seem to when I generate the file using python. I've edited my original question; am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @user366202: You need to lock the file before writing it. Open the file with open and use `fcntl.flock` on it before writing (numpy.savetxt() support writing to file descriptors). Remember to release the lock after writing. [Example 5 on this page](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/1605/fcntl.flock) shows the mechanism